# Getting negative values while incrementing numbers in a while loop

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that will calculate how many days I will need to save X amount of money if I increment the daily contribution by the previous and initial values every day.

Eg: my starting contribution on day 1 is 2, then on day 2 it will be 4, day 3 it will be 6 etc, so the total money in the pot for 3 days will be 12.

My program at the moment looks like this:

```
    int startingValue = 2;
    int dailyAmount = startingValue;
    int pot = 0;
    int desiredMoney = 43554;
    int daysSaved =0;


    while (pot != desiredMoney){

        pot += dailyAmount;
        dailyAmount += startingValue;
        daysSaved++;
    }

    System.out.println("Daily amount needed : " + dailyAmount + " Days saved : " + daysSaved + " Money in the pot : " + pot);
```

Current output of this program is this :

```
Daily amount needed : 294923972 Days saved : 147461985 Money in the pot : 43554
```

which doesn't look quite right, but I am not sure why. When I run it in debug mode, it makes sense for the first couple of runs, but when I put the `sout` statement inside the `while` loop after a while I see negative numbers such as these:

```
Daily amount needed : 1054054 Days saved : 527026 Money in the pot : -1415942538
```

I would expect to see `daysSaved` as around 1000 days, but my program is clearly broken. Will appreciate any help!

Comment: the condition should be `while (pot < desiredMoney){`

Comment: `pot != desiredMoney` is unlikely to be met as it would need to be _exactly_ equal so the integers are likely wrapping from overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: why do you get negative numbers when adding? *Integer Overflow*. Java's `int`s are 32 bit signed integers. The max safe value for a signed integer is `2147483647`. Add just `1` to that it will roll over into `-2147483648`.

Read more about [integer overflows on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

For the second part of your question. `pot != desiredMoney` is *very* unlikely to happen, since you keep adding an ever increasing number to your pot.  The semantic you want is probably `pot < desiredMoney`; keep doing this loop while the pot is less than the desired amount of money.